# Codeigniter - database creation using $this->dbforge->create_database() not working in server

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

```
public function create_db($dbname,$db_user,$db_password)
{ 
    $this->load->dbforge();
    $this->dbforge->create_database($dbname);
    $this->db->query("CREATE USER '". $db_user ."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '". $db_password ."';");
    $this->db->query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON  ".$dbname.". * TO '". $db_user ."'@'localhost';");
    return $dbname;
}
```

In my project, i want a new database to be created while registering a new user. Thus i used the above code and the database was created with the given name.
It works fine in local. But when i hosted it in server, it gives error and no database creation occured.

Output

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check, if `$dbname` has a value?

Comment: This could mean you do not have a database connection that works.

Comment: @Vickel I tried entering value manually too. Still not working

Comment: @DFriend database connection is working perfectly fine.

Comment: do you have permission to create database ?

Comment: figured out the probelm ! i dont have the permission to create the database .. thank you @Bira

Comment: Well done, please up vote, thank you!