# Creating a new database is not working at server in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, cpanel

I have a accounting management project where I need to store some specific data to a new database. I am fetching a issue when I am going to create a new database in server. It is working fine in local. As this project is made with Codeigniter 3, I am using codeignite dbforge() library to create new databse.

I have made this following this documentation of codeigniter 3.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/forge.html#database-forge-class

```
// First Code
if (!$this->dbutil->database_exists($newDb)){
    $this->dbforge->create_database($newDb);
}
```

But when I run this code, I get this error message.

> Error Number: 1044
>
> Access denied for user 'shohowqj_testing_usr'@'localhost' to
> database 'shohoz_hishab_backup_2022'
>
> CREATE DATABASE `shohoz_hishab_backup_2022` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
> utf8_general_ci
>
> Filename: modules/yearly_closing/controllers/Yearly_closing.php
>
> Line Number: 68

Here "shohowqj_testing_usr" is my current username of database.

Then I researched on google and stackoverflow. I tried with some other way to fix it. But it did not work.

I found this question and answer of stackoverflow and I implemented accourdingly. But it is yet not working.

[Codeigniter - database creation using $this->dbforge->create_database() not working in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403841/codeigniter-database-creation-using-this-dbforge-create-database-not-work)

This is my code

```
$newDb = 'shohoz_hishab_backup_'.date('Y');
$db_user = 'new_user';
$db_password = 'new_password';
if (!$this->dbutil->database_exists($newDb)){
    $this->dbforge->create_database($newDb);
    $this->db->query("CREATE USER '". $db_user ."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '". $db_password ."';");
    $this->db->query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON  ".$newDb.".* TO '". $db_user ."'@'localhost';");
}
```

This code is showing the same error message.

I am using cpanel in my server. This error is showing in server only. But it is working fine on local machine.

I have given the full permission of my existing user named "shohowqj_testing_usr". See this image bellow.

[image]

Please advise me if there is any other way to fix it or if I have made any mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted about this issue on Codeigniter forum, One of them answered me to follow the code to create a new database. But this is not working as well.


`// You can also pass another database object to the DB Forge loader,
// in case the database you want to manage isn’t the default one:

$this->myforge = $this->load->dbforge($this->other_db, TRUE);

// NOTE: my_db is a database configuration file in database.php
// not the default one.

if ($this->dbforge->create_database('my_db'))
{
        echo 'Database created!';
} `

Comment: One more idea I get from codeigniter forum user is "you need to create a seperate config for a new database in app/Config/Database.php otherwise Database Forge, or it will use the default database group."

`public $default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
    ]; `

Comment: I posted on facebook codeigniter groups about this. But one of them said, as I am using cpanel and shared hosting, I need permission to create database. But they will not give it due to shared server.